# Error PHP end of while using PDO Wrapper

Tags: php, pdo, while-loop

Hope can help.

Using [php-pdo-wrapper-class](http://code.google.com/p/php-pdo-wrapper-class/) I am trying to do 'while' to put results in table.

So far:

```
$preNic = $db->select('g1_pimps', 'id > 0', 'id, nick, STATUS', '50');
$i=0;
while ($preNic[$i])
{
echo $preNic[$i]['nick'].' - '.$preNic[$i]['id'].'<br />';  
$i++;       
}
```

$preNic gives this array

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 2
        [nick] => PimpNo_2
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 3
        [nick] => PimpNo_3
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 4
        [nick] => PimpNo_4
    )

etc
)
```

Now it works but:
a. Is it right way?
b. It gives error notice at end.

Comment: What notice? Undefined offset?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using a while loop use a foreach:

```
foreach($preNic as $row){
   echo $row['nick'].' - '.$row['id'].'<br />'; 
}
```

Foreach's are Pimp, Hope it helps

Comment: Yep perfect, your a life saver.

Comment: np, Your tend to use less `while loops` now your using PDO. If you have an array foreach is what your wanna use :)